# Remove ambiguity in grammar for expression casting

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, jison

I'm working on a small translator in JISON, but I've run into a problem when trying to implement the cast of expressions, since it generates an ambiguity in the grammar when trying to add the production of cast. I need to add the productions to the cast option, so in principle I should have something like this:

```
expr: OPEN_PAREN type CLOSE_PAREN expr
```

However, since in my grammar I must be able to have expressions in parentheses, I already have the following production, so the grammar is now ambiguous:

```
expr: '(' expr ')'
```

Initially I had the following grammar for expressions:

```
expr                :       expr PLUS expr
                    |       expr MINUS expr
                    |       expr TIMESexpr
                    |       expr DIV expr
                    |       expr MOD expr
                    |       expr POWER expr
                    |       MINUS expr %prec UMINUS
                    |       expr LESS_THAN expr
                    |       expr GREATER_THAN expr
                    |       expr LESS_OR_EQUAL expr
                    |       expr GREATER_OR_EQUAL expr
                    |       expr EQUALS expr
                    |       expr DIFFERENT expr
                    |       expr OR expr
                    |       expr AND expr
                    |       NOT expr
                    |       OPEN_PAREN expr CLOSE_PAREN
                    |       INT_LITERAL
                    |       DOUBLE_LITERAL
                    |       BOOLEAN_LITERAL
                    |       CHAR_LITERAL
                    |       STRING_LTIERAL
                    |       ID;
```

Ambiguity was handled by applying the following precedence and associativity rules:

```
%left                       'ASSIGNEMENT'
%left                       'OR'
%left                       'AND'
%left                       'XOR'
%left                       'EQUALS', 'DIFFERENT'
%left                       'LESS_THAN ', 'GREATER_THAN ', 'LESS_OR_EQUAL ',  'GREATER_OR_EQUAL '
%left                       'PLUS', 'MINUS'
%left                       'TIMES', 'DIV', 'MOD'
%right                      'POWER'
%right                      'UMINUS', 'NOT'
```

I can't find a way to write a production that allows me to add the cast without falling into an ambiguity. Is there a way to modify this grammar without having to write an unambiguous grammar? Is there a way I can resolve this issue using JISON, which I may not have been able to see?

Any ideas are welcome.

This is what I was trying, however it's still ambiguous:

```
expr: OPEN_PAREN type CLOSE_PAREN expr
    | OPEN_PAREN expr CLOSE_PAREN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't specify the precedence of the cast operator, which is effectively a unary operator whose precedence should be the same as any other unary operator, such as `NOT`. (See below for a discussion of `UMINUS`.)

The parsing conflicts you received are not related to the fact that `expr: '(' expr ')'` is also a production. That would prevent LL(1) parsing, because the two productions start with the same sequence, but that's not an ambiguity. It doesn't affect bottom-up parsing in any way; the two productions are unambiguously recognisable.

Rather, the conflicts are the result of the parser not knowing whether `(type)a+b` means `((type)a+b` or `(type)(a+b)`, which is no different from the ambiguity of unary minus (should `-a/b` be parsed as `(-a)/b` or `-(a/b)`?), which is resolved by putting `UMINUS` at the end of the precedence list.

In the case of casts, you don't need to use a `%prec` declaration with a pseudo-token; that's only necessary for `-` because `-` could also be a binary operator, with a different (reduction) precedence. The precedence of the production:

```
expr: '(' type ')' expr
```

is `)` (at least in yacc/bison), because that's the *last* terminal in the production. There's no need to give `)` a shift precedence, because the grammar requires it to always be shifted.

Three notes:

1. Assignment is right-associative. `a = b = 3` means `a = (b = 3)`, not `(a = b) = 3`.
2. In the particular case of unary minus (and, by extension, unary plus if you feel like implementing it), there's a good argument for putting it ahead of exponentiation, so that `-a**b` is parsed as `-(a**b)`. But that doesn't mean you should move other unary operators up from the end; `(type)a**b` should be parsed as `((type)a)**b`. Nothing says that all unary operators have to have the same precedence.
3. When you add postfix operators -- notably function calls and array subscripts -- you will want to put them *after* the unary prefix operators. `-a[3]` most certainly does not mean `(-a)[3]`. These postfix operators are, in a way, duals of the prefix operators. As noted above, `expr: '(' type ')' expr` has precedence `')'`, which is only used as a reduction precedence. Conversely, `expr: expr '(' expr-list ')'` does not require a reduction precedence; the relevant token whose shift precedence needs to be declared is `(`.

So, according to all the above, your precedence declarations might be:

```
%right          ASSIGNMENT
%left           OR
%left           AND
%left           XOR
%left           EQUALS DIFFERENT
%left           LESS_THAN GREATER_THAN LESS_OR_EQUAL GREATER_OR_EQUAL 
%left           PLUS MINUS
%left           TIMES DIV MOD
%right          UMINUS
%right          POWER
%right          NOT CLOSE_PAREN
%right          OPEN_PAREN OPEN_BRACKET
```

I listed all the unary operators using right associativity, which is somewhat arbitrary; either `%left` or `%right` would have the same effect, since it is impossible for a unary operator to compete with another instance of the same operator for the same operand; for unary operators, only the precedence level makes any difference. But it's customary to mark unary operators with `%right`.

Bison allows the use of `%precedence` to declare precedence levels for operators which have no associativity, but Jison doesn't have that feature. Both Bison and Jison do allow the use of `%nonassoc`, but that's very different: it says that it is a syntax error if either operand to the operator is an application of the same operator. That restriction is, for example, sometimes applied to comparison operators, in order to make `a < b < c` a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way this problem is handled is by having `type` names as distinct keywords that can't be expressions by themselves.  That way, after seeing an `(`, the next token being a `type` means it is a cast and the next token being an `identifier` means it is an expression, so there is no ambiguity.

However, your grammar appears to allow type names (`INT`, `DOUBLE`, etc) as expressions.  This doesn't make a lot of sense, and causes your parsing problem, as differentiating between a cast and a parenthesized expression will require more lookahead.

The easiest fix would be to remove these productions (though you should still have something like `expr : CONSTANT_LITERAL` for literal constants)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have already corrected the code, actually INT, DOUBLE, CHAR etc, are literal constants. I have placed the corresponding productions, however the grammar is still ambiguous.